# Hill-jumping game mechanic like Tiny Wings

Tags: box2d, game-mechanics

I'm a huge Tiny Wings fan and I'd like to understand the game mechanic at a deeper level. **What are some good resources for the basic Box2d (or similar) physics behind the hill-jumping game mechanic?**

I've used some basic features of Box2d. I imagine the flying character is just a circle, tapping the screen increases the downward force on the character, and the hills are some sort of curve object from the physics engine.

**Edit #1** Here's more info: I'd like to understand which objects from the Box2d physics library are used to create the bare-bones hill-jumping mechanic. This mechanic would look like a "curvy" horizontal line that just scrolls across the screen. The most basic shape for this line that comes to mind is a sine wave so that's probably a good starting point.

Then there's the character that moves around. Note the character's horizontal position is fixed while the vertical position moves up and down. I'm curious about which Box2d body shape, type etc is used for this character. What are some values for the coefficient of friction that work well? How about the density etc.

I've searched around the web for tutorials that ideally will answer the above questions and perhaps provide additional resources regarding efficiency, camera motion and so on.

Comment: Maybe you can give more details for those unfamiliar with the game mechanics? Just asking for "good resources" isn't a good fit for a Q/A site, since it just generates a list, without a correct answer. Perhaps you can be more specific about what you're wanting as well.

Comment: @Byte56 sure thing. Please see updated question.

Comment: related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26291/ http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33944/

Comment: If you really like this type of game, see: [Yellow Fins](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/yellow-fins/id494225934?mt=8), [Angry Hills](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/angry-hills/id450440552?mt=8), [Hamster Ball](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/hamster-ball/id460784363?mt=8), [Rocket Chicken](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/rocket-chicken-fly-without/id495951303?mt=8), [Crazy Little Skier](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/crazy-little-skier-hd/id432463596?mt=8), [PenguinWings](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/penguin-wings/id473589463?mt=8),

Comment: [WhenPigsFly](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/when-pigs-fly-free/id471650809?mt=8), [Space Dragons](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/space-dragons/id439228061?mt=8), and [Insane Skaters](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/insane-hill-skaters/id493322622?mt=8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out this tutorial by Ray Wenderlich. It uses Cocos2d + Box2d to show how to write a game like Tiny Wings.

The first part of the tutorial explains how to create dynamic textures:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3888/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-1

Second part is how to use Box2d for the gameplay:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3913/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-2